# The meaning of the angle of Fourier coefficients.

Tags: fourier-analysis

I was wondering what is the meaning of the [argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)) of fourier transform?

It is known that the amplitude space happens to be useful and sometimes people even refer to fourier transform as a transformation to amplitude space directly.

It is generally said, that the amplitude measures how much of a certain frequency is present in a signal, which is rather straightforward and intuitive.

I have not however found any explanation for the angle of fourier coefficients ( [angle or argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)) ). It is interesting to know, what would it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phase in a sense measures the alignment of two signals. For example, consider the two signals $u_1(t) = e^{2\pi it}$ and $u_2(t) = e^{i\delta}e^{2\pi it}$, where $\delta$ is some real number. Both signals have the same frequency and amplitude. However, depending on $\delta$, the signals might combine in different ways. Let $v = u_1+u_2$, then $v = (1+e^{i\delta})e^{2\pi i t}$.

Now notice the following:

- When $\delta=0$, $v = 2u_1$ and $|v|=2$. This is constructive interference.
- When $\delta = \pi$, $e^{i\delta} = -1$ and $v=0$. This is destructive interference.

Other values of $\delta$ are somewhere in between. This shows how the phase is supremely important in determining how two signals interact. Coincidentally, this the reason that quantum mechanics uses complex probability amplitudes: so that the probability of a combination of states can destructively interfere such as in the [double slit experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment), for example.

Answer (score 1):

The angle represents delay, or *phase*.  The sum of sinusoids is not uniquely-defined unless you pick a phase offset between them.